Foreign movie about two young brothers
I need help finding the name of this movie that I'm guessing was made anywhere from 1985 - 2005. It was from a Hollywood video store or from a Blockbuster. I remember watching this foreign movie as a kid and now can only remember a few scenes.
I remember they were small and they were hiding from soldiers. One got caught and they were separated from each other. I remember them finding each other later on. They liked the same girl and fought over her. One brother stabbed the other in the knee with a red pocket knife. I also remember them driving a yellow school bus off of a cliff and jumped out before it went over while singing something in their foreign language.

The French drama Le fils du requin (AKA Son of the Shark) from 1993.

Brothers Martin and Simon, not yet teens, are incorrigible vandals; Martin runs away from reform school, Simon from foster homes, and they always find each other in a seacoast town of Lignan, where their destructive behavior is infamous. (It may date to their mother's leaving the family.) Martin is philosophical, romantic, and poetic: he dreams of being the son of a shark; he holds tight to a book about goldfish his mother gave him. In both halting and wild ways, he tries to court Marie, a neighbor girl. Simon, with a pocketknife and an intractable will, seems more dangerous to others.

Here's the scene with them singing while driving a bus off a cliff:




You're officially the user14111 of M&TV.
